# windows shares not accessible on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: smb

I am new to linux, i did do an admin course a long time ago 2001 but a lot has changed and that was redhat. My problem is i have several shares on a Windows 10 pc (set up without password protection) and the firewall is turned off. All the windows based pc's have no problem accessing these shares without the need for username and password but my ubuntu laptop always asks for username and password. At first i thought SMB was not installed so i installed it but this did not help. What am i missing?

Comment: Have you tried with the username guest and no password?

Comment: I don't have windows machines that I care to mess with at this time, but have you read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) or [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide) - I think these imply that you need to install *cifs*, and do a little configuration.

Comment: @Tobias. Username guest with no password not working.

Comment: @Charles Green i will have a look at thouse articals and see if they help

Comment: Interestingly i didnt have this problem on playlinux beta1

Comment: Did you enable the guest account for the share? It might make guest/blank password work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157852/windows-10-asks-for-network-credentials-even-though-password-protected-sharing

Answer (score 1):

I know this is now old, but if it's windows 10 and you're using a windows account, there is a simple way to log in with smb.

Assuming the MS account name is name@domain.com, do the following:

```
User: name
Domain: domain.com
Password: password
```